# LINQ query: restrict child entity

Tags: c#, linq

I'm novice in LINQ, so I need an initial help how to simplify writing of LINQ queries. Here my scenario: I have two tables C_Systemtype with 1:M relationship to CT_Systemtype, using database first approach.

**Class C_System:**

```
{
    public string SystemtypeId { get; set; }
    public bool Is_productive { get; set; }
    public bool Is_systemown { get; set; }
    public bool Is_active { get; set; }
    public byte[] Icon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CT_Systemtype> CT_Systemtype { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<C_System> C_System { get; set; }
}
```

**Class CT_Systemtype:**

```
{
    public string SystemtypeId { get; set; }
    public string LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Descript { get; set; }    
    public virtual C_Systemtype C_Systemtype { get; set; }
    public virtual S_Language S_Language { get; set; }
}
```

I like to select all C_Systemtype but with CT_Systemtype restricted to a given LanguageId.

I believe the following LINQ query is working (p_langId is my parameter):

```
using (var db = new PaltrConnect())
        { var query = from s in db.C_Systemtype
                      join t in db.CT_Systemtype on s.SystemtypeId equals t.SystemtypeId
                      where t.LanguageId == p_langId 
                      select new { s.Is_productive,
                                   s.Is_systemown,
                                   s.Is_active,
                                   s.Icon,
                                   s.CT_Systemtype }
         }
```

The result is of type anonymous. My intention is something like C_Systemtype.Include(t => t.CT_Systemtype) but with additional restriction on CT_Systemtype.

How can I rewrite this query in such a way that I don't have to give each property in the select part and to finally map individual properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are joining two tables together you can't just return a single type. To prevent having to map each property in the select you can use something like AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var db = new PaltrConnect())
{ 
var query = from s in db.C_Systemtype
                  join t in db.CT_Systemtype on s.SystemtypeId equals t.SystemtypeId
                  where t.LanguageId == p_langId 
                  select s ;/*s is your C_Systemtype*/
     }
```